# jQuery autocomplete not working for multiple text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the issue that autocomplete on works for the first textbox, but not for the other ones that I can add via a button. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('positionen')" />
<input class="button" type="button" value="-" onclick="deleteRow('positionen')" />
<table id="positionen">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" /></td>
        <td><input class="ui-widget" type="text" name="text[]"  placeholder = "Text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name = "val[]" placeholder = "Val" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Function addRow:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                    break;
            case "checkbox":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Function deleteRow:

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Can't delete all rows");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Autocomplete code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".ui-widget").focusin(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: 'search.php'
        });
    });
});
```

The first textbox that is already on the page by default is working fine with autocomplete. However when I add a textbox with the button, autocomplete is not working for this textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Events are bind to the html when page is loaded, new rows are not there, you just need to bind it to the created rows by simply adding this to your addRow function

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                    if (newcell.childNodes[0].className === 'ui-widget ui-autocomplete-input') {
                        $(newcell.childNodes).autocomplete({
                            source: 'search.php'
                        });
                    }
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                    break;
            case "checkbox":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "row.autocomplete" is not working for me. However when I do "$(".ui-widget").autocomplete({
   source: 'search.php'
  });" it's working fine!

Comment: My mistake :), Ive forgotten to to put row inside $(). If you "$(".ui-widget").autocomplete({ source: 'search.php' });" you are binding events to existing rows - you autocomplete event will be called few times which is wrong - edited answer

Comment: I see... I was trying to bind it to the row. Now should work. I think it is good idea to add it while you adding childnodes (couldve benn done later but then you will have to iterate over row structure). Sorry for me being clumsy :)

Comment: how will new nodes have `ui-widget ui-autocomplete-input` class?

Comment: Whole table cell is being created from existing one in html - newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;